# Push single List<> Elements in a ListView with custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

i have a problem with my custom `ArrayAdapter`. I have in my `ArrayAdaper` a `List<Object>` with some data. The data come from a another class `DataContainer`. I have some methods to filter my `List<Object>` and push the `List<Object>` with a foreach loop in 2 `TextViews` (Song Title = TextView1, Songwriter,Genre = TextView 2) Now its look like:

[image]

How can I handle the List to push a single element in each listView row like this :

[image]

Have somebody tips?

this is my adapter

```
    public class MusicFragmentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Music> implements DataManager.MusicCallback {
    private final int resourceId;
    private final Activity activity;


    public MusicFragmentAdapter(Activity context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
        resourceId = resource;
        activity = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMusic(final List<Music> music) {

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setItems(music);
            }
        });
    }


    public void setItems(List<Music> itemList) {
        clear();
        for (Music item : itemList) {
            add(item);
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //data from your adapter
        Music itemData = getItem(index);

        if (convertView == null) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());


            convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, null);

        }

        setViewContent(index, convertView, itemData);

        return convertView;
    }

    protected void setViewContent(int index, View itemView, Music itemData) {
                final TextView titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        final TextView subText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subText);

        StringBuilder titleText = new StringBuilder();
        DataManager dataManager = MusicApplication.getDataManager();



        List<Music.Entry> musics = dataManager.getDataContainer().getMusicOfMonth("april").getMusics();

        for(Music.Entry music : musics){
            titleText.append(music.getMusicEntry().getMonth();
            titleText.append("-")
            titleText.append(music.getMusicEntry().getSongTile()+"\n");
        }
        titleTextView.setText(titleText.toString());

        StringBuilder subText = new StringBuilder();
        for(Music.Entry subs : musics){
            subText.append("Genre: " + subs.getMusicEntry().getGenre() + "\n");
            subText.append("Songwriter: " + subs.getMusicEntry().getSongwriter()+ "\n");
        }
        subText.setText(subText.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you are using the adapter properly. You shouldn't need a for loop to fill the list with data. Just assign the arraylist to the adapter. And make a custom view for each item.

Comment: I fill the list with the datacontainer its a seperate class that handle data how i get from a Server  , with the for each loop  push the list values with a stringbuilder in 2 textviewd

Comment: Can you post the custom `ArrayAdapter` code?

Comment: Look at my edit @GeorgeMulligan

Comment: Is this code inside `getView()`? Can you add the whole custom `ArrayAdapter`? It appears you are a bit confused on how to set it up properly. Each call to `getView()` should return the view for a single item to be displayed. You usually get access to the item to setup by calling `getItem(int position)` from within `getView()`.

Comment: No this code is in a method setContentView i call this method in getView and yes i also call getItem (index) like Music item = getItem (index).

The data how i fill the list is sort by maps

Comment: show my Edit @GeorgeMulligan

Comment: This was my mistake i modify somethink for a better understanding, not List<MusicBib.Entry> rather this List<Music.Entry>, i Edit this

Comment: Use a different layout structure that contain three textviews ( Title,Genre,And Song writer)

Comment: in Music is a List<Entry> , a method to add the Music by the Month and a getter for the List<Entry> getMusic(); return List<Entry>;

Entry is the inner Class from Music with this Class i have acces to MusicEntry, MusicEntry have fields like Songwriter,Genre blabla

Comment: no this dont work @Krish

Comment: Why? It will make it simpler logics

Comment: As per your design you are using three TextViews right?

Comment: @Krish No i using 2 one for the title and the other one for the subtext

Look an my screenshots , the first show how it looks now and the second i want